# programatically binding a listview in xamarin c#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a listview in Xamarin portable, 
the item source of the listview is `List<String>` and my datatemplate of the listview is prepared by this function,

```
private DataTemplate createItemtemplate()
{
    try
    {
        Label lbl_binding = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Red,
            FontSize = 16,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        };
        lbl_binding.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");
        StackLayout stkBottom = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Padding = new Thickness(0),
        };
        stkBottom.Children.Add(lbl_binding);
        ViewCell vc = new ViewCell() {
            View = stkBottom
        };

        DataTemplate Dp = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            return vc;
        });
        return Dp;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, my list view is populated, but all the **labels are filled with last item**, I mean the no of items are rightly populated, but all the items are filled with the last item only.
what i am doing wrong here?

```
lstAdmin = new ListView()
{
    ItemTemplate = createItemtemplate(),
};
lstadmin.Itemsource = source;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AdminCell : ViewCell
{
    public AdminCell()
    {
        Label lbl_binding = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.FromRgb(30, 144, 255),
            FontSize = 16,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        };
        lbl_binding.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");
        StackLayout stkBottom = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Padding = new Thickness(0),
        };
        stkBottom.Children.Add(lbl_binding);
        View = stkBottom;
    }
}
```

this code is working for me removed the template and use this cell, i still don't understand why the data template is not working

Answer (score 0):

Change your listview from List to ObservableCollection. This should do the work.

Comment: Please, edit your question and show me how you're filling the list.

Comment: And how you're setting this data template to the listview

Comment: @Thava I guess that `listview.ItemsSource = source` is the problem. You need to define your ItemsSource property just once and then add your itens to it. It's very recommended you use it as a bind , following the MVVM pattern, avoiding this kind of struggles, but we can handle it. Try to set `listview.ItemsSource = new List<string>()` at your constructor and then add your itens to it like `((List<string>)listview.ItemsSource).Add("stringToAdd")`

Comment: Thanks  @Diego but still the same problem persists

Comment: What the hell is going on, man?! Last try: post all your code xaml, code behind and outher classes if you have. I'll try reproduce same error here

Answer (score 0):

Below code useful for you as reference

**Take Class members:**

```
   public class Dummy
    {

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Img { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    }
```

**Create One ObservableCollectionList:**

```
   ObservableCollection<Dummy> productItems = new 
   ObservableCollection<Dummy>();
```

**Add Items to the ObservableCollectionList:**

```
   productItems.Add(new Dummy() { Name = "0", Img = "Avatar.png", 
   Title = "Total Books", SubTitle = "Desc", Count = "50", Status = 
   "Total" });

   productItems.Add(new Dummy() { Id = "1", Img = "Avatar.png", Title 
   = "Out of Stock Books", SubTitle = "Desc", Count = "40", Status = 
   "OutStock" });
```

**Declare ListView:**

```
   ListView listview = new ListView()
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
            RowHeight = 30,
        };
listview.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(cell));
listview.ItemSelected += listviewItemSelected;
```

**Take ViewCell and design your UI in ViewCell and assign binding**

```
    public class cell : ViewCell
    {
        public cell()
        {
            Image img = new Image()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            };

            img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Img"));

            Label lbltitle = new Label()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                TextColor = Color.Black
            };

            lbltitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new 
           Binding("Title"));

            Label lbldesc = new Label()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                TextColor = Color.Black
            };

            lbldesc.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new 
            Binding("SubTitle"));

            StackLayout lblstack = new StackLayout()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Children = { lbltitle, lbldesc },
            };
            BoxView boxEdit = new BoxView()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
                Color = Color.Black,
                HeightRequest = 20,
                WidthRequest = 10
            };

            tapGestureEdit.Tapped += tapGestureEditTapped;
            Label lblCount = new Label()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                TextColor = Color.Black
            };
            lblCount.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new 
            Binding("Count"));
            StackLayout stackCount = new StackLayout()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                Children = { boxEdit, lblCount },
            };
            StackLayout stackMain = new StackLayout()
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Children = { img, lblstack, stackCount },
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10)
            };
            View = stackMain;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately create a view cell show me some errors, i have already apply this in a control and also added a renderer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after some tests I've figured out how to not get always the last item.

You should put the Label creation ,and all the other elements you want put as `ItemTemplate`, inside the lambda of the `DataTemplate` like this (example code) :

```
DataTemplate itemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                Label label = new Label()
                {
                    Margin = new Thickness(45, 0, 0, 0),
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    FontSize = (double)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources["BodyFontSize"],
                    HeightRequest = 20
                };
                label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");

                ViewCell templateCell = new ViewCell()
                {
                    View = label
                };

                return templateCell;
            });
```

Hope that helps (helped in my case).