# xamarin forms listview empty Textcell

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to generate a listview with data i get from a server.

```
private class Entry
{
    public string entry { get; set; }
}
private void ListMenue()
{
    List<Entry> lentry = new List<Entry>();
    for (int e = 0; e < menueItems.Count; e++ ){
        lentry.Add(new Entry { entry = menueItems[e]["name"].ToString() });
    }
    DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
    template.SetValue(TextCell.TextColorProperty, Color.Black);
    template.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "entry");
    ListView lListView = new ListView { ItemsSource = lentry, RowHeight = 40, ItemTemplate = template};
}
```

WIth this Code the ListView shows blank Items. They are there but the Text seems to be empty. But if I dont add a Template to the listView and just set the Itemsource with a list of strings it works fine. But the text Color is Pink then. I Can't find the mistake. Here is the version that shows pink text:

```
private void ListMenue()
{
    private List<string> lentry = new List<string>;
    for (int e = 0; e < menueItems.Count; e++ ){
        lentry.Add(menueItems[e]["name"].ToString());
    }
    ListView lListView = new ListView { ItemsSource = lentry, Rowheight = 40};
}
```

I think the binding doesnt work but I dont know how to set it correctly in c#.

Comment: use this link for the reference : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589449/programatically-binding-a-listview-in-xamarin-c-sharp

Comment: Which platform did you build ?I used your code and it works fine on my iphone

Comment: I tested the app on Android.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. It seems to be an Android API bug. At Android Manifest I set min SDK to 22 and at Android project - Properties - Link Options I set only SDK-Assemblys. I cleaned the project afterwards. I hope this helps. Ty Lucas. You helped me to search the solution by showing me that the app actually works.l